# ERROR! This is a JHipster blueprint and should be used only like jhipster --blueprint

Tags: jhipster

I tried creating a new blueprint using the steps provided in the
[jhipster website](https://www.jhipster.tech/modules/creating-a-blueprint/)

but I face the following issue,

```
➜  sampleProj jhipster --blueprint testbp     
INFO! Switching to JHipster installed locally in current project's node repository (node_modules)
INFO! No custom sharedOptions found within blueprint: generator-jhipster-testbp at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-testbp
INFO! No custom commands found within blueprint: generator-jhipster-testbp at /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster-testbp
ERROR! This is a JHipster blueprint and should be used only like jhipster --blueprint testbp
Error: This is a JHipster blueprint and should be used only like jhipster --blueprint testbp
    at module.exports.error (/home/user1/code/jhipster/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1889:11)
    at new module.exports (/home/user1/code/testbp/generators/app/index.js:12:18)
    at Environment.instantiate (/home/user1/code/jhipster/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:801:23)
    at Environment.create (/home/user1/code/jhipster/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:773:17)
    at /home/user1/code/jhipster/generator-jhipster/cli/program.js:189:58
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async JHipsterCommand._lazyBuildCommandCallBack (/home/user1/code/jhipster/generator-jhipster/cli/program.js:179:13)
    at async JHipsterCommand._parseCommand (/home/user1/code/jhipster/generator-jhipster/cli/jhipster-command.js:79:7)
    at async JHipsterCommand.parseAsync (/home/user1/code/jhipster/generator-jhipster/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:916:5)
```

The /generators/app/index.js file has the following check,

```
const jhContext = (this.jhipsterContext = this.options.jhipsterContext);

if (!jhContext) {
   this.error(`This is a JHipster blueprint and should be used only like ${chalk.yellow('jhipster --blueprint angularFuse')}`);
}
```

I couldn't figure out how/where the `jhipsterContext` object is being set in the code. The only reference that I could see is in `/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base-blueprint.js`

```
// jhipsterContext is the original generator
this.jhipsterContext = this.options.jhipsterContext;
```

which doesn't help me much.

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Might not be the root cause but the option is --blueprints with an  s not what you used.

Comment: make sure generator-jhipster dependency was added to your package.json. Also don't forget to run npm install.

Comment: Same problem! JHipster is great but it fails on the documentation about creating your own blueprint